# AWS .NET Serverless/SAM: Can I use AuthorizeAttribute on a Lambda function?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am trying to incorporate .NET's `AuthorizeAttribute` in my AWS Serverless Application Model project.  In my `startup.cs` class, which is decorated with `[LambdaStartup]`, in  `ConfigureServices()`, I have the following:

```
services.AddAuthorization(authorization =>
{
    authorization.AddPolicy("HasDocReadPrivilege", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("privileges", Constants.DocsReadPermission);
    });
});
```

And in `Configure()` I have `app.UseAuthorization();`

In my `Functions.cs` I have added the `Authorize` attribute to the function I wish to enforce authorization on, as follows:

```
[Logging(LogEvent = true, CorrelationIdPath = CorrelationIdPaths.ApiGatewayRest)]
[Metrics(CaptureColdStart = true)]
[Tracing(CaptureMode = TracingCaptureMode.ResponseAndError)]
[Authorize("HasDocReadPrivilege")]
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> MyFunction(
    APIGatewayProxyRequest request, 
    ILambdaContext context)
{
    //Do something
}
```

But it doesn't work.  Even if I set `Constants.DocsReadPermission` to a value that is not included in the user's claims (parsed from the authorization header which contains a JWT bearer token), it still allows the user to call the function.

What am I doing wrong?  Or is it simply that AWS Lambda functions don't recognize the `Authorize` attribute?